# How to return a field from firebase which depends on what the UID equals to

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve a field from my firestore database. When a user is logged in, I am able to get his/her uid, but I have another collection called restaurants, where inside I have documents of added restaurants. Each restaurant has the UID also included.
What I'm trying to do, is to retrieve the data of the restaurant and specifically that one that has the field uid equal to the logged in user.

**this is the structure that I have of the database:**

[image]

So I'm trying to return a `ListTile` which will provide the user options to edit the owned restaurant, and then another `ListTile` of added meals.

**The `ListTile` looks like this:**

[image]

The problem is that I can't find the correct way on how to retrieve those fields

My code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> _restaurantStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('restaurant')
    .where(uid, isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .snapshots();

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return LoadingScreen();
        }
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Overview'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
                  document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

              Future<void> editRestaurant() async {
                final isValid = _form1.currentState.validate();
                {
                  if (!isValid) {
                    return;
                  }
                }
                if (isValid) {
                  _form1.currentState.validate();
                  User user = _auth.currentUser;

                  Restaurant _restaurant = Restaurant(
                    name: _name,
                    preparationTime:
                        double.parse(_preparationEditingController.text),
                    deliveryFee: double.parse(_feeEditingController.text),
                    uid: user.uid,
                  );

                  // Call the user's CollectionReference to add a new user
                  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('restaurant')
                      .doc(data['rid'])
                      .update(_restaurant.toMap())
                      .then((_) => print(uid))
                      .catchError((error) =>
                          print("Failed to edit restaurant: $error"));
                  print('restaurant Edited');
                }
              }

              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Card(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                                title: const Text(
                                  'Edit your restaurant',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                // subtitle: Text(DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm').format(widget.order.dateTime)),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(_expanded
                                      ? Icons.expand_less
                                      : Icons.expand_more),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _expanded = !_expanded;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              if (_expanded)
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15,
                                    vertical: 10,
                                  ),
                                  child: Form(
                                    key: _form1,
                                    child: ListView(
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text('Name:    '),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                onSaved: (val) =>
                                                    _nameEditingController
                                                        .text = val,
                                                onChanged: (val) {
                                                  _name = val;
                                                },
                                                decoration:
                                                    const InputDecoration(
                                                        counterText: ''),
                                                // controller: _nameEditingController,
                                                maxLength: 20,
                                                initialValue: data['name'],
                                                textInputAction:
                                                    TextInputAction.next,
                                                validator: (value) {
                                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                                    return 'Please provide a name';
                                                  }
                                                  return null;
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text('Prep Time:    '),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                onSaved: (val) =>
                                                    _preparationEditingController
                                                        .text = val,
                                                // controller: _nameEditingController,
                                                maxLength: 5,
                                                initialValue:
                                                    data['preparationTime']
                                                        .toString(),
                                                decoration:
                                                    const InputDecoration(
                                                        counterText: ''),
                                                textInputAction:
                                                    TextInputAction.next,
                                                keyboardType:
                                                    TextInputType.number,
                                                // onFieldSubmitted: (_) {},
                                                // onEditingComplete: () {},
                                                validator: (value) {
                                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a number';
                                                  }
                                                  if (double.tryParse(value) ==
                                                      null) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a valid number';
                                                  }
                                                  if (double.parse(value) <=
                                                      0) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a greater number';
                                                  }
                                                  return null;
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Text('Delivery Fee:    '),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                onSaved: (val) =>
                                                    _feeEditingController.text =
                                                        val,
                                                // controller: _nameEditingController,
                                                maxLength: 5,
                                                initialValue:
                                                    data['deliveryFee']
                                                        .toString(),
                                                decoration:
                                                    const InputDecoration(
                                                        counterText: ''),
                                                textInputAction:
                                                    TextInputAction.done,
                                                keyboardType:
                                                    TextInputType.number,
                                                // onFieldSubmitted: (_) {},
                                                // onEditingComplete: () {},
                                                validator: (value) {
                                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a number';
                                                  }
                                                  if (double.tryParse(value) ==
                                                      null) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a valid number';
                                                  }
                                                  if (double.parse(value) <=
                                                      0) {
                                                    return 'Please enter a greater number';
                                                  }
                                                  return null;
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 15,
                                        ),
                                        ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: editRestaurant,
                                            child: const Text('Save changes')),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
      stream: _restaurantStream,
    );
  }
```

**Restaurant Model**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'menu_item_model.dart';

class Restaurant {
  String rid;
  String uid;
  String name;
  List<String> tags;
  List<MenuItem> menuItems;
  double preparationTime;
  double deliveryFee;

  Restaurant(
      {this.rid,
      @required this.uid,
      @required this.name,
      this.tags,
      this.menuItems,
      @required this.preparationTime,
      @required this.deliveryFee});

  //send data to the server
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'rid': rid,
      'uid': uid,
      'name': name,
      'tags': tags,
      'menuitems': menuItems,
      'preparationTime': preparationTime,
      'deliveryFee': deliveryFee,
    };
  }

// receive data from server
  factory Restaurant.fromMap(map) {
    return Restaurant(
      uid: map['uid'],
      rid: map['rid'],
      name: map['name'],
      menuItems: map['menuItems'],
      preparationTime: map['preparationTime'],
      deliveryFee: map['deliveryFee'],
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. and any suggestions on how to improve the structure to get the data in a simpler way would also be great!

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as there is way more code here than we can analyze in a reasonable amount of time. Showing less code with the same problem, means you'll have a better change of getting an answer. --- That said, the query you do seems correct. If you're not getting the expected documents back fro the database, you might want to check of `user.uid` has the correct value when you use it in `.where(uid, isEqualTo: user.uid)`. Running the code in a debugger is the fastest way to check this.

Comment: You may refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911384/how-to-get-data-from-cloud-firestore-where-user-uid-equal-to-document-id-in-flut)  which also mentions about retrieving data from firestore and then using a comparison from another document.